# AWS Cloudformation Add Confirm Password parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloudformation template on AWS and have successfully added the username and **password** parameter which is required as a user input.
But is there any way to add **"Confirm password"** field as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finally worked after I specified 3 parameters - username, password, confirm password and then added the following rule section in the template:

JSON:

```
"Rules" : {
    "matchPasswords" : {
        "Assertions" : [
        {
            "Assert" : {"Fn::Equals":[{"Ref":"Password"},{"Ref":"ConfirmPassword"}]},
            "AssertDescription" : "Passwords do not match"
        }
        ]
    }}
```

YAML:

```
Rules:
  'matchPasswords':
    Assertions:
      - Assert:
          Fn::Equals:
            - Ref: 'Password'
            - Ref: 'ConfirmPassword'
        AssertDescription: 'Passwords do not match'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could accept 3 parameters - username, password, confirm password. Specify a condition like "password-match" and then, add this condition to all your resources. So if the passwords don't match, nothing will be created.

Check this page to understand the use of conditions better https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html

Comment: It was helpful.. But still the UI shows stack creation complete. 
Is there any way to validate it before executing create stack? 
like we can do with parameters by adding constraints